# Inserting object dependency in WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a user with `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount` and I'm having problems to insert the object 'User' that has a 'Client' like its dependency.

My code:

```
var client = new UserRepository(context).GetByEmail(email);

token = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
        email,
        password,
        new
        {
              name,
              email,
              isAdmin,
              client
        });
```

This code throws this exception:

> No mapping exists from object type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Client_3003777381BB2D4BFAC2DAB15BF164994D9EE8AB84E8AF4BED6DC161613271BB to a known managed provider native type.

My models:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Monitoring> Monitoring { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string email { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you post your models? You are missing one of the attributes or using a different attribute name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount()` can handle only simple types (up to string) and therefore cannot map your class reference. You can do the following:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string email { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public int ClientId;

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

and now

```
token = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
    email,
    password,
    new
    {
          name,
          email,
          IsAdmin = isAdmin,
          ClientId = client.Id
    });
```

You should check the name of the ClientId field in the database. It can also be named `Client_Id`. You should update your code accordingly in this case.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge Stephen! It worked well.

Comment: If you do not mind, could you please mark this answer as your preferred answer to help others as they see that this question has been answered (and of course I would like to get the reputation :-))

Comment: Of course Stephen! Sorry for this, I'm new here and I'm getting used to! Sorry and thank you! ;)